# I can choose best model based in value of AUC PR-curve instead f1-score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, auc, precision-recall

I want to argue my choice of best model obtained, however there is one model that has a higher f1-score value than another (by very little). But, when graphically visualizing the test results, the other model is better which has a lower f1-score value. When I compare their PR-curve AUCs, the value obtained from the model with the lower f1-score is higher (also by very little).

Is it possible to argue that I have chosen this model as better because it has a higher PR-curve AUC?

THANK YOU

The problem is a binary classification with very unbalanced data. It should be noted that it is complicated to explain why visually it is better for me, also it is for a formal report so I want to correctly justify my choice.

Comment: Compare also the log-losses, I feel the visually better model will have a smaller logloss.

Answer (score 0):

F-score is threshold sensitive. Default sklearn threshold of 0.5 might be suboptimal. Good PR curve suggests searching for better thresholds, consider this vectorized example:

```
probabilities = model.predict_proba(X_test)    
precision, recall, thresholds = sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve(y_test, probabilities)
f1_scores = 2 * recall * precision / (recall + precision)
best_f1 = np.max(f1_scores)
best_thresh = thresholds[np.argmax(f1_scores)]
```

Worth noting F-measure is also class specific. If you seek a statictically correct model, it is worth comparing class independent and threshold independent metrics like logloss foremost, as threshold selection should not (ideally) be mixed with model evaluation.